# Enable C++14 support in CLion?

Tags: c++14, clion

Is there a way to enable C++14 in CLion?
Currently my code compiles, but the syntax highlight marks many lines as errors that are correct C++14. Is there a setting that I can use or something to enable C++14 support in the editor of CLion?

**Update:** Any updates in CLion 1.2 regarding C++14 support?

Comment: CLion probably doesn't have support for the features in C++14, yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now clion supports c++14. `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)` in `CMakeLists.txt`

Answer (score 4):

No progress so far. CLion 1.2 officially supports C++11, but only with some missing features according to their web page.
For upcoming 1.5 for which the [EAP program is open](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/CLION/Early+Access+Program) until now there are also no additional C++14 features. As per today the C++14 features are not assigned to a developer or any version in the ticketing system. The [roadmap for 1.5](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/CLION/Roadmap+for+CLion+1.5) says nothing about C++14 support.

Comment: whey you say "not supported" does this mean proper code won't compile, or clion features (unrelated to compilation) just don't work on some code that is otherwise valid?

Comment: CLion features just don't work. I compiled C++14 code using CLion which delegated it via CMake to gcc or clang.